# How to measure reaction time in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to measure the reaction time for when a user presses a button, This is what I have so far,

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
    $stop = false;
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        if(isset($_POST['butt'])){
            $stop = true;
        }
    }
    if($stop == true){
        $time_end = microtime(true);
        $time = $time_end - $time_start;
        echo "<h1> Reaction time: " . $time . "</h1>";
    }
```

I am not getting the correct time using this method. Essentially I want a counter that starts when a button is pressed and ends when another button is pressed.

Comment: Because of network latency this approach will not get you reasonable results. You need to measure time intervals with JavaScript on the client side (meaning in the browser).

Comment: @lukas.j, thanks that makes a lot of sense. I am using the JS method provided by below.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done with single request.

If you want to use php for this. You have to send request when first button is clicked and store timestamp somewhere (i.e. session).

```php
<form method="post">
    <button onclick="event.preventDefault();fetch('?firstClick=1')">first button</button>
    <button type="submit" name="butt">second button</button>
</form>

<?php

// handle first click
if (isset($_GET['firstClick'] && $_GET['firstClick'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['firstClickTimestamp'] = microtime(true);
}

// handle second click
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['butt']) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['firstClickTimestamp'])) {
        $time_end = microtime(true);
        $time = $time_end - $_SESSION['firstClickTimestamp'];
        echo "<h1> Reaction time: " . $time . "</h1>";
    } else {
        echo "<h1>First button was not clicked!</h1>";
    }
}
```

But this can be done easily with javascript.

```js
var firstClick = null;
var secondClick = null;

function onFirstClick() {
    firstClick = Date.now();
}

function onSecondClick() {
    secondClick = Date.now();
    showReactionTime();
}

function showReactionTime() {
    if (firstClick && secondClick) { document.getElementById('reactionTime').innerHTML = `<h1>Reaction time: ${secondClick - firstClick}  milliseconds</h1>`;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="reactionTime"></div>
<button onclick="onFirstClick()">first button</button>
<button onclick="onSecondClick()">second button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, The javascript method seems to work more reliably.